# Wallester decrypting cvv from API

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a payment card data from wallester throught API. But whenever I try to decode the data, the library just giving me error, also online tools are not very helpful. I Have no Idea, where it can be a problem, if you guys have made something in wallester, please let me know.

I have made a code in python to get this, but I'm lost in this moment. Wallester support is not helping at all.

```
import json
import base64
import jwt
import requests
import rsa
import time


def get_encrypted_card_number(api_key, rsa_public_key, rsa_private_key, card_id):
    # Generate the JWT token

    jwt_private_key = rsa_private_key.encode()

    timestamp = int(time.time())
    claims = {
        "api_key": api_key,
        "ts": timestamp
    }
    jwt_token = jwt.encode(claims, jwt_private_key, algorithm="RS256")

    request_data = {
        'public_key': base64.b64encode(rsa_public_key.encode()).decode()
    }
    headers = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + jwt_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    url = f"https://api-frontend.wallester.com/v1/cards/{card_id}/encrypted-card-number"

    # Send the API request
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(request_data))


    response_data = response.json()
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("API request failed")

    response_data = response.json()

    res = response_data['encrypted_card_number']
    res = res.replace("-----BEGIN CardNumber MESSAGE-----", "")
    res = res.replace("-----END CardNumber MESSAGE-----", "")
    res = res.replace("\n", "")
    print(res)

    encrypted_card_number = base64.b64decode(res.encode())

    # Decrypt the card number
    private_key = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(rsa_private_key.encode())
    decrypted_card_number = rsa.decrypt(encrypted_card_number, private_key).decode()

    return decrypted_card_number

# Example usage
api_key = ""

with open("private.pem", "r") as f:
    rsa_private_key = f.read()

with open("public.pem", "r") as f:
    rsa_public_key = f.read()
card_id = "ce7b54a6-8165-49e1-97b2-bca7af5abaa5"

decrypted_card_number = get_encrypted_card_number(api_key, rsa_public_key, rsa_private_key, card_id)
print(f"Decrypted card number: {decrypted_card_number}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered with the same issue on Node.js.
It didn't work until I've added label.

Here is my Node.js example. Hope it helps.

```
const cardNumberBase64Encoded = cardNumberPem.replace(/\n/g, '')
.replace('-----BEGIN CardNumber MESSAGE-----', '')
.replace('-----END CardNumber MESSAGE-----', '');

const decryptedData = crypto.privateDecrypt(
   {
       key: encPkcs8Pem,
       padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,
       oaepHash: "sha256",
       //
       // IMPORTANT
       // IMPORTANT
       // IMPORTANT
       // IMPORTANT
       oaepLabel: Buffer.from("CardNumber"), // <======
       // IMPORTANT
       // IMPORTANT
       // IMPORTANT
       // IMPORTANT
       //
   },
   Buffer.from(cardNumberBase64Encoded, 'base64'),
);

console.log(decryptedData.toString());
```